# Collapse option type creation

Tags: f#, pipeline, option-type, type-inference

If I specify function value as:

```
let applyFirst f elements = 
    if Seq.isEmpty elements then None else elements |> Seq.head |> f
```

then F# infers the `f` type as `f: 'a -> b' option`. It's ok, I understand why F# infers `f`'s return type as `'b option`. But I want `f` to be `f: 'a -> 'b`, and it can be done by changing `applyFirst` function:

```
let applyFirst f elements = 
    if Seq.isEmpty elements then None else elements |> Seq.head |> f |> Some
```

But wonder if there's some more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
let applyFirst f elems = elems |> Seq.tryPick (f >> Some)
```

But I think I prefer

```
let applyFirst f elems = 
    if Seq.isEmpty elems then 
        None 
    else 
        Some( f(Seq.head elems) )
```

as more readable.

Comment: Isn't the latter version less functional and more imperative?

Comment: @Dmitry, no, it's not imperative (still just one big effect-free expression).  Regardless, IMO the goal of software is not to come up with the most functional/elegant solution if that means trading away readability.  Some engineers may find the first version as readable, but I am not among them; I need to expend a bit more brainpower to read that one line than to read the four lines of the other one.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that readability is the key. And for me the latter one is more readable, but I've just started to learn F# so the latter version seems more... natural to me. But at the same time the former version is more concise, so I hope that sometimes it will be more readable for me :)